# Interview: Design Netflix Software Stack

Tags: architecture, cloud, backend

I was recently asked this in an interview and didn't really know how to go about answering the question.

Few Basic Ideas:

- API calls to know which stream to grab
- Tons of video data stored, need to be able to index that very quickly to provide the user with their movie
- Client-side loading of the video
- seeking 3/4 way ahead during a video, how to load the video from there (send an api call that gives the video ID, and the timing i.e. 1:34:00, and the call will provide a stream from there?)

Any tips on how to tackle these type of problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks from your example that they did not specify which component in the Netflix end to end solution they were interested in or even if it was just the client side or the server side.

If this is correct then the question is probably more to see how you approach a problem like this, in which case your breaking it down is a good start.

Netflix clients run on a large variety of devices and there will not be a single software stack across them all.

The netflix video distribution side is largely dependent on a Content Distribution Network (CDN) which is essentially a network that gets the content close to the user so the user can access it over the regular internet for the last bit of the contents journey. The CDN will have lots of different software stacks in it.

On the server or headend side, Netflix will have many different systems to store the content, to store metadata about the content, to store user account info, to store performance and analytics info, to transcode the content into the various formats they need to deliver it in etc etc, so again there will not be just one stack.

In summary, hopefully the intent of the question was not to get an exact answer, but just to see how you approached it (or it maybe its was just a bad question!!).

(And no, I don't work for Netflix!).